# Получение битов из байтов

Tags: java, android, byte

Например есть 8 байт данных.
Есть стартовый байт и стартовый бит - откуда нужно взять информацию, а также длина в битах(сколько нужно взять).

Как я могу достать из этих 8 байт например, с первого байта - 7 и 8 бит (т.е. стартовый байт №1, позиция стартового бита №7, длина 2 бита)

или например, с 3го бита второго байта взять 14 бит (то есть используется второй и третий байт)

Comment: Почитайте про битовые операции и булевую алгебру. Операциями & and | or ~not  >>сдвиг <<сдвиг решается это. В качестве альтернативы придуман java *bitstream*. эту библиотеку можно скачать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того чтобы не "воевать" самому с битовыми операциями, можно воспользоваться стандартным классом [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

```
public static BitSet getBitSet(byte[] array, int fromByteIndex, int fromByteBitIndex, int bitsCount)
{
    BitSet arrayBitSet = BitSet.valueOf(array);
    int fromIndex = fromByteIndex * 8 + fromByteBitIndex;
    return arrayBitSet.get(fromIndex, fromIndex + bitsCount);
}
```

И использование:

```
byte[] array = { 10, 1, 127 };
BitSet result = getBitSet(array, 1, 7, 2);
System.out.println(result.get(0));
System.out.println(result.get(1));
```

> false
>   true

---

В `BitSet` индексы битов определяются так:

```
10 = 00001010
     76543210 - индексы
```

Если нужен обратный порядок:

```
10 = 00001010
     01234567 - индексы
```

то, как вариант, можно предварительно менять порядок битов в байтах:

```
public static BitSet getBitSet(byte[] array, int fromByteIndex, int fromByteBitIndex, int bitsCount)
{
    byte[] reversedBitsOrderArray = new byte[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        reversedBitsOrderArray[i] = reverseBitsOrder(array[i]);
    }
    BitSet arrayBitSet = BitSet.valueOf(reversedBitsOrderArray);
    int fromIndex = fromByteIndex * 8 + fromByteBitIndex;
    return arrayBitSet.get(fromIndex, fromIndex + bitsCount);
}

private static byte reverseBitsOrder(byte b)
{
    byte from = b;
    byte to = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        to <<= 1;
        to |= (from & 1);
        from >>= 1;
    }
    return to;
}
```

В принципе, в этом случае решение "взять биты вручную" становится короче и проще:

```
public static boolean[] getBits(byte[] array, int fromByteIndex, int fromByteBitIndex, int bitsCount)
{
    boolean[] bits = new boolean[bitsCount];
    int fromIndex = fromByteIndex * 8 + fromByteBitIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < bitsCount; i++)
    {
        int byteIndex = (i + fromIndex) / 8;
        int bitIndex = (i + fromIndex) % 8;
        bits[i] = (array[byteIndex] & (1 << (7 - bitIndex))) != 0;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Comment: написал специальное приложение по работе с машинными кодами. Для реализации математики использовал BitSet, очень удобная штука. Советую автору вопроса воспользоваться именно этим решением.

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев если только одна проблема: `BitSet` работает с little-endian. Я сейчас сижу думаю как изящнее решить проблему, если автору нужен big-endian.

Comment: Спасибо. Я ни как не соображу, следующий код:  byte[] testArr = new byte[]{10, 5, 127};BitSet bitSet = Helper.getBitSet(testArr, 1, 5, 2); bitSet.get(0) = true, а bitSet.get(1) = false должно же быть? или я не так понимаю? пытаюсь достать 5й и 6й бит - байта 5 = 00000101

Comment: @DuosDuo по-моему, вы как раз про то, о чём я писал выше. Только я это ещё не очень корректно назвал. Суть в чём: в `00000101` 0й бит - это `1`, 1й - это `0`, 2й - `1` и т.д.

Comment: @DuosDuo добавил в ответ вариант с обратным порядком битов

Comment: Спасибо за разжевывание:) Но я не совсем понял порядок индексов для байта 5. Для 10 идет по порядку от 0 до 7 (8 битов), а для 5 не понятно что происходит.

Comment: @DuosDuo а что именно непонятно? Я в ответе написал (сейчас малость его упростил, оставив индексы одного байта), что разница в том, что вы считаете первым битом в байте: для `00000101` это либо `0` в начале, либо `1` в конце. То есть нумеруете ли вы биты справа налево, или слева направо

Comment: Вроде я понял) Не сообразил что мне нужно считать не с начало в конец, а наоборот. Все выходит.. Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста, а как я могу собрать из этих битов - байты? например мне известно 2 бита "10" - как мне собрать из этого 00000010 и перевести в 10тичную систему. Может мне будет известно 3 бита "101" как из этого сделать 00000101 - цифра 5 в 10тичной, имею ввиду как это сделать правильно... Спасибо

Comment: @DuosDuo, установка бита получается аналогичным образом. Например, есть байт b, хотим в позиции pos установить бит: b | (1 << pos). Всё, этого достаточно. Как занулить pos бит (т.е. поставить нуль): b & ~(1 << pos). ~ - это побитовое инвертирование битов.

Comment: @DuosDuo, но есть проблема установки бита таким способом: приходится облагать проверкой, то, что мы хотим сделать. Если устанавливаем бит, один код, если устанавливаем нуль - другой. На такую "элементарную" (в плане процессорной сложности) операцию, как установка бита, жалко накладывать условие, так как его будет пытаться предсказывать branch predictor (предсказатель переходов), дабы не разрушить конвейер процессора. Но, к счастью, можно обойтись без этого условия, усложнив выражение установки бита: (bit * ~0) ^ (((bit * ~0) xor b) | (1 << pos)) - где ^ - побитовый xor.

Comment: @DuosDuo с вариантом `101` -> `10100000` справился бы `BitSet`, а вот `101` -> `00000101`, вероятно, проще написать вручную

Comment: Ребят, я дополнил вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста..

Comment: @DuosDuo добавлять в вопрос код из ответа к этому вопросу, а также спрашивать в вопросе что-либо по ответу на этом вопрос здесь не принято. Стоило описать это в комментарии или, что лучше, задать новый вопрос со ссылкой на этот. По поводу `BitSet`: так уж он устроен, поэтому чтобы получить массив из 4 байтов, придётся написать так: `array = Arrays.copyOf(result.toByteArray(), 4);`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

Как это устроено "под капотом":

```
public static boolean getBitFromByte(byte b, int position) {
        // position = 6 - т.е. хотим получить 7 бит
        // 11010110 - b
        // & - побитовая операция И
        // 01000000 == (1 << 6) - сдвиг влево на 6 позиций (битов)
        // =
        // 01000000
        // затем сдвигаем обратно на 6 позиций вправо:
        // 01000000 >> 6 == 00000001 - что означает 7-й бит 
        //     данного байта b равен 1 (единице)
    return ((b & (1 << position)) >> position) == 1;
}

public static boolean getBitFromBytes(byte[] bs, int bytePos, int bitPos) {
    return getBitFromByte(bs[bytePos], bitPos);
}

public static byte setBitInByte(byte b, boolean bit, int position) {
    if (bit)
        return (byte)(b | (1 << position));
    else
        return (byte)(b & ~(1 << position));
}

// почему-то нельзя преобразовать в Java тип boolean к int, не используя условие
// поэтому приходится передавать установочный бит в типе int
public static byte setBitInByteFast(byte b, int bit, int position) {
    return (byte) (((1 - bit) * ~0) ^ ((((1 - bit) * ~0) ^ b) | (1 << position)));
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    byte b = 0;
    b = setBitInByte(b, true, 3);
    System.out.println(getBitFromByte(b, 3));
    b = setBitInByte(b, false, 3);
    System.out.println(getBitFromByte(b, 3));
    b = setBitInByteFast(b, 1, 3);
    System.out.println(getBitFromByte(b, 3));
    b = setBitInByteFast(b, 0, 3);
    System.out.println(getBitFromByte(b, 3));
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь в развитии))

Comment: комментарии данные вами в коде тоже играют не маловажную роль..
return (b & (1 << position)) >> position == 1 - я правильно понял?

Comment: (b & (1 << position)) >> position - в этом случае чем является цифра 1? Например в нашем случае если нужно получить 5й байт что то меняется?

Comment: @Regent, да, вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: @DuosDuo, в первом комментарии вы правильно поняли. Насчёт второго: 1 - значение типа int, так как в Java по умолчанию числовые литералы приводятся к int. Но по идее лучше конечно привести к типу byte. Хотя пока не вижу проблем, которые могут возникнуть.

Comment: А как мне занулить первые n битов в байте?

Comment: DuosDuo, добавил код для установки бита.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте побитовый AND:

```
byte[] bytes = {-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
System.out.println((bytes[0] & 0x80) == 0x80); // 0x80 - 1000 0000 в двоичном коде 
System.out.println((bytes[0] & 0x40) == 0x40); // 0x40 - 0100 0000 в двоичном коде
```

Результат:

```
true
true
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я не совсем понимаю как я это буду использовать.